# Django: How to send username across all the pages once the user is logged in

Tags: django

Here is the login method in the view:

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request, user)
            return redirect('forum')
        else:
            messages.info(request, 'Username or password is wrong!')
            return render(request, 'login.html')
    return render(request, 'login.html')
```

Here is how I wrote my codes:
In the **views** module: I've register method and login method which both work properly.
However, I've other methods who required login in order to access them, since I redirect only a page at a time, I can't get the same username across the pages that required login before to access them.
Now the problem is, how to create another page who treats data came from the forum  by conserving the same username from the loggin.
PS: In the forum, I can get the username but how to maintain the same username, is the problem
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

If I understood the issue, you want to use `user` after login.

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request, user)
            return redirect('forum')
        else:
            messages.info(request, 'Username or password is wrong!')
            return render(request, 'login.html')
    return render(request, 'login.html')

def another_page(request, *args, **kwargs):
    user = request.user
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In every template you can get username from *user* object:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
{{ user.username }}
{% endif %}
```

*user* is an object that django shares to it's templates